# Overwriting group of values with in same column another set of group based on other column group

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Input:

```
Name   GroupId Processed   NewGroupId  NgId
Mike   1          N         9          NULL
Mikes  1          N         9          NULL 
Miken  5          Y         9          5
Mikel  5          Y         9          5

Output:

Name   GroupId Processed   NewGroupId  NgId
Mike   1          N         9          5
Mikes  1          N         9          5
Miken  5          Y         9          5
Mikel  5          Y         9          5
```

below query worked in sql server, due to correlated subquery same is not working in spark sql.
Is there any alternate either with spark sql or pyspark dataframe.

```sql
SELECT Name,groupid,IsProcessed,ngid,
       CASE WHEN ngid IS NULL THEN
       COALESCE((SELECT top 1 ngid FROM temp D 
       WHERE D.NewGroupId  = T.NewGroupId  AND 
       D.ngid IS NOT NULL  ), null)
       ELSE ngid 
       END AS ngid 
FROM temp T
```

Answer (score 0):

worked with below in sparksql.

```
spark.sql("select LKUP,groupid,IsProcessed,NewGroupId ,coalesce((select Max(D.ngid) from test2 D where D.NewGroupId = T.NewGroupId AND D.ngidis not null),null) as ngid from test2 T")
```